# How can I import all groups and the member of groups hierarchy into a csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I output the Membership of Active Directory Groups using PowerShell in a tree structure? I am using Windows Server 2012. It should match a parent group to a child group.

For example:

```
Groups     Member of
Group-1    Test group-1
           Test group-2
Group-2    Test group-3
           Test group-4
```

Comment: It's going to be really hard to format a table like that. Like not worth the time in my opinion.

Comment: What is the task you are trying to accomplish?  Maybe we can give a better solution than importing from csv?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` to get Group membership for Group objects:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter *
$output = foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $GroupMemberships = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $Group
    if ($null -ne $GroupMemberships) {
        foreach ($GroupMembership in $GroupMemberships) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Group = $Group.Name
                Memberof = $GroupMembership.Name
            }
        }
    } else {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Group = $Group.Name
                Memberof = "None"
            }
    }
}
$output | Format-Table
$output | export-csv C:\example.csv -notypeinformation
```